# Platform of gem tzinfo-data for both 32bit and 64bit Ruby on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tzinfo

Our development computer has both 32 and 64bit `ruby` installed. The `tzinfo-data` needs to specify the platforms which blows up the Rails 4.2 app.

For 64bit ruby, the `Gemfile` has:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw, :mingw, :mswin]
```

For 32bit ruby, the `Gemfile' has:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw_20, :mingw, :mswin]
```

App blows up if running 32bit ruby with 64bit platform or vise verse.

How to specify platform which is good for both 32 and 64bit ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on both 32-bit and 64-bit Ruby:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw, :mingw, :mswin]
```

You could also remove the `platforms` option altogether:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

Make sure that you've run the `bundle update` command with both your 32-bit and 64-bit Ruby versions to install the tzinfo-data gem into that Ruby installation.

For more information about what the `platforms` option does, please refer to the [Gemfile manual page](http://bundler.io/v1.11/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-).